# codeigniter's link does not work and cannot match with the function parameter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have the function

```
index($errorMsg, $successMsg) {....}
```

It works when I type in the URL.

```
http://localhost/website/index.php/home/index/1234/5678
```

But It does not work But when I type in the URL.

```
http://localhost/website/index.php/home/index//5678
```

5678 will be $errorMsg.

Is there any hints

Comment: Yeah, don't do this. It's all sorts of smelly. Don't pass error or success messages via get - surely you already know them?? Also you could use the code igniter's router if you need more complex routes: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: ` http://localhost/website/index.php/home/index/{what's in here??}/5678`

Answer (score 1):

Really bad solution for passing success or error parameters via function arguments by get method in CI.

Try use session flash data to pass success or error messages in redirection view.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('errorMsg', '1234');
$this->session->set_flashdata('successMsg', '5678');
```

And show variables:

```
function index() 
{
   echo $this->session->flashdata('errorMsg');
   echo $this->session->flashdata('successMsg');
}
```

Use this solution to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Your solution**

Declare function like this

```
index($errorMsg, $successMsg=NULL) {....}
```

**Explanation**

`index($errorMsg, $successMsg)` function required both arguments(variables). If you don't pass it will produce error which is happening in your case.

`index($errorMsg, $successMsg=NULL)` function required first one and 2nd one is optional.If you don't pass 2nd argument `$successMsg` value will be null.

**Note**

`/home/index//5678` no need use double slash after index.One will solve your purpose.You need to just check `$successMsg`.If it is null means you passed only `$errorMsg`